# the deploying with capistrano and uploads directory with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I use Capistrano for déploiment of my website.
The encounter problem is that every time I deploy my site with capistrano in production, it keeps me not upload images into production and it crushes me all.

How do keeps me picture uploads into production when I made a déploiment in production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to make sure you set :linked_dirs in your deploy.rb e.g. for one of my sites paperclip uploads to the public/system directory so I need to make sure I symlink that one:

```
set :linked_dirs, ['log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system']
```

EDIT: For me this creates a symlink in `[cap deploy dir]/current/public/system` which goes to `[cap deploy dir]/shared/public/system`

Incase you didn't know before you deploy again check your `[cap deploy dir]/releases` you should find some of your old deploys so you might be able to recover your uploads.

---

From the gem github page (https://github.com/capistrano/rails):

**Symlinks**

You'll probably want to symlink Rails shared files and directories like log, tmp and public/uploads. Make sure you enable it by setting linked_dirs and linked_files options:

```
# deploy.rb
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads')
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy with capistrano, everytime a new version of code is created.
Each version is actually a seperate folder, which is the reason you have to upload your images again and again for each deployment.

You can symlink your directories so that each version of code is served the images from the common location.

```
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('bin', 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle')
```